# spring data jpa specification select related 3 tables

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, criteria-api

I have entities like below ;

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Card> cards;
}
```

---

```
  @Entity
public class Card {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private CardType type;

    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "card", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Product> products;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private Integer count;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Card card;
}
```

---

```
public enum CardType {
    SPECIAL, STANDART
}
```

---

**I am trying to get Customers which has Products in their Speacial type Card.**

Example Data ;

**customers**

```
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | mike   |
|  2 | john   |
|  3 | robert |
|  4 | sam    |
+----+--------+
```

**cards**

```
+----+----------+-------------+
| id |   type   | customer_id |
+----+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SPECIAL  |           1 |
|  2 | SPECIAL  |           2 |
|  3 | SPECIAL  |           3 |
|  4 | STANDART |           4 |
+----+----------+-------------+
```

**products**

```
+----+----------+---------+
| id |   name   | card_id |
+----+----------+---------+
|  1 | product1 |       1 |
|  2 | product2 |       2 |
|  3 | product3 |       2 |
|  4 | product4 |       4 |
+----+----------+---------+
```

**The query result  should be customers with name "mike" and "john" because there are products in their special cards.**

I have tried the code below but it is not working:

```
 public static Specification<Customer> hasSpecialProduct() {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            Join<Customer, Card> customerCardJoin = root.join(Customer_.cards, JoinType.INNER);
            Predicate cardTypeSpecialPredicate = cb.equal(customerCardJoin.get(Card_.type), CardType.SPECIAL);
            Predicate existsProductsPredicate= cb.exists(customerCardJoin.get(Card_.products));
            return cb.and(cardTypeSpecialPredicate, existsProductsPredicate);
        };
    }
```

How can I do it with Specification? 
can somebody help me?

Comment: Your mapping is incorrect. Read the Hibernate manual to find out how to correctly map bidirectional OneToMany associations.

Comment: @JBNizet what part is incorrect ?

Comment: The cards OneToMany association. It needs a mappedBy attribute, as explained in the manual.

Comment: @JBNizet I have corrected it. Do you know how I create this query ?

Comment: I wouldn't use a criteria query for such a static query. JPQL is much easier to read. But you probably want `cb.isNotEmpty(customerCardJoin.get(Card_.products))`

Comment: @JBNizet thanks, I change existProductsPredicate with yours, now it is working but also I want to select not for this query. I tried cb.not(cb.and(cardTypeSpecialPredicate, existsProductsPredicate)); I expect that it returns other customer but it return all customer. can you help me ?